# list of 2D array in java

Tags: java, list, collections, multidimensional-array

i have set of 2D arrays and i want store all 2D arrays into single list how can do this in java?

Comment: Is "core" the proper tag here?  I don't think so, but I'm very new here.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just pass the set into a list like so:

```
    int [][]a = new int[3][3];
    Set<int[][]> set = new HashSet<int[][]>();
    set.add(a);
    ArrayList<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<int[][]>(set);
```

Or am I not understanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

e.g. or what do you mean

```
int[][] a2d = new int[15][15];
int[][] b2d = new int[10][10];
List<int[][]> list2d = new ArrayList<int[][]>(10);
list2d.add(a2d);
list2d.add(b2d);
```

or do you mean you have a `Set<int[][]>` then you can simply do what tpierzina suggested

```
List<int[][]> list2d = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
list2d.addAll(nameOfYourSetVariable);
```

or

```
List<int[][]> list2d = new ArrayList<int[][]>(nameOfYourSetVariable);
```

Comment: List <double[][]> twoDimArrayList=new ArrayList<double[][]>();
i have done like this but it is showing error arraylist cannot be resolved type

Comment: Have you imported ArrayList? I mean `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: add `import java.util.*;` to the top of your file

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String[][]> myFunc( Set<String[][]> s ) {
  List<String[][]> l = new ArrayList<String[][]>( s.length() );
  l.addAll( s );
  return l;
}
```